# Why doesn't language:lang-none work?

Tags: discussion, tags, syntax-highlighting

I tried using `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to display the output of a program without any syntax highlighting at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081895/c-vector-seems-to-be-overwritten-on-for-loop. However it still displayed the output like it is in some kind of language, displaying the text in various colors.

Here's a brief snippet of that text:

```
|A| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-|

|-| |A| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-|
```

Is `<!-- language: lang-none -->` not supported properly, or am I using it incorrectly?

**EDIT**

Perhaps my browser, chrome, is responsible. Here's an image of what I see before I added this section.

[image]

Comment: I see nothing colored in that code block. You use the lang-none correctly.

Comment: Are you talking about the grey background? That's not syntax highlighting. That's **always** part of the rendering of a code block, syntax highlighting or no syntax highlighting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, No, I am talking about the colored text. The imaged I added to the question shows that.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is the coloring of different types of syntax in a piece of computer code to make them visually differ from other types. Like `vector` rendered in blue, while `<string>` next to it is being rendered in dark red in the C++ code.

Comment: @RSahu: there is no colored text there. I see black text on a grey background.

Comment: @RSahu: perhaps your *display* is having trouble with the vertical lines? You probably are seeing artifacts *caused by the hardware of your display*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that very well may be the case. Let me check on a different computer.

Comment: Despite that it should be impossible, his screenshot at least does have colours when zoomed in. http://i.stack.imgur.com/kW0tV.png Probably something between his browser/OS/graphics driver is trying to do subpixel rendering shenanigans poorly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are seeing, but that block is **not** syntax highlighted.

When you inspect the elements with your browser developer tools, you see:

```
<pre class="lang-none prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="pln">|A| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-|

|-| |A| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-|

|-| |-| |A| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-| |-|

[.... elided ....]

</span></code></pre>
```

There are no `<span>` elements with tokens normally found in highlighted source code.

Compare this to the C++ code section:

```
<pre class="lang-cpp prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="kwd">void</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="typ">Grid</span><span class="pun">::</span><span class="pln">create</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="typ">vector</span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="typ">Aphid</span><span class="pun">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> aphidVector</span><span class="pun">,</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="typ">vector</span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="typ">Ladybug</span><span class="pun">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> ladyVector</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="com">// ============= Aphid initial draw section ============================</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="typ">vector</span><span class="str">&lt;string&gt;</span><span class="pln"> vertical</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="kwd">this</span><span class="pun">-&gt;</span><span class="pln">height</span><span class="pun">);</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="typ">vector</span><span class="str">&lt;string&gt;</span><span class="pln"> horizontal</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="kwd">this</span><span class="pun">-&gt;</span><span class="pln">length</span><span class="pun">);</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="kwd">unsigned</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="typ">int</span><span class="pln"> j</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
string aphid </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="str">"|A|"</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
string ladybug </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="str">"|L|"</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
string empty </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="str">"|-|"</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="kwd">for</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="typ">vector</span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="typ">Aphid</span><span class="pun">&gt;::</span><span class="typ">iterator</span><span class="pln"> aphIt </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> aphidVector</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">begin</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln">
        aphIt </span><span class="pun">!=</span><span class="pln"> aphidVector</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">end</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">++</span><span class="pln">aphIt</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">

    pair</span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="typ">int</span><span class="pun">,</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="typ">int</span><span class="pun">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> temp_pos </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(*</span><span class="pln">aphIt</span><span class="pun">).</span><span class="pln">getPosition</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln">
    </span><span class="kwd">for</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">j </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln"> j </span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="pln"> vertical</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">size</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln"> j</span><span class="pun">++)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">
        </span><span class="kwd">if</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">j </span><span class="pun">==</span><span class="pln"> temp_pos</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">first</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">
            </span><span class="kwd">unsigned</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="typ">int</span><span class="pln"> i</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
            </span><span class="kwd">for</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">i </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln"> i </span><span class="pun">&lt;</span><span class="pln"> horizontal</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">size</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln"> i</span><span class="pun">++)</span><span class="pln">
                </span><span class="kwd">if</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">i </span><span class="pun">==</span><span class="pln"> temp_pos</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">second</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">
                    horizontal</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">at</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">i</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> aphid</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
                </span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="kwd">else</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">
                    horizontal</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">at</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="pln">i</span><span class="pun">)</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> empty</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
                </span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln">

[... more elided ...]

</span></code></pre>
```

So apart from not showing any colors when rendered, none of the `<span class"[tokentype]">` elements that normally are there to tell the browser what colors to use are not even there.